# add "categories" heading programatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building one application for uploading documents, and I am having one problem with which I need help.
The administrator is able to add categories in which the users can upload the documents. On the page where the documents are shown, they need to be shown under which category they are uploaded. 
All the info is stored in the database, I want to know how I can display that nicely. Categories and under each categories, files for that category.
Thanks for your help in advance, Laziale

Comment: nothing so far, I have only one panel where I am displaying all the documents without separating them in categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User treeview to display the parent nodes as categories and the child as the uploded document name.

```
Category1
    |
     ___ Uploded Doc1
     ___ Uploded Doc2
    |
Category2
    |
     ___ Uploded Doc3
```

Not sure if you need something else. But please mention in detail what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend the JTree which is made by JQuery, it is great and convenient.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution can be having a reference to each category from its documents, and then loop through the documents first and a nested loop through each category's documents. Code should look like this:

```
foreach (Category cat in myCategories)
{
   // create a new Label for Category Title
   // lblCat.Text = cat.Title;

   foreach (Document doc in cat.Documents)
   {
      // create another new Label beneath the category label
      // lblDoc.Text = doc.Title;
   }
}
```

An alternative solution cab be creating a table (like `HtmlTable` control) and adding it on the page at runtime.